# How to use two arrayList in one adapter Android studio Java?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I know this question asked before but I couldn't understand and integrate this into my code. I have 2 arraylist.One for api data and the other for database data.Database's arraylist working successful when it's alone. But when I add the API's arraylist, i get this exception
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

This is Fragment file;

```
RecyclerView cuzdan_rc;
private ArrayList<CuzdanModel> cuzdanModels;
CuzdanAdapter adapter;

private VeriTabani vt;
CoinMarketApi api;




private List<Datum> cuzdanList =null;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.varliklarim_fragment_layout, container, false);
    vt = new VeriTabani(getActivity());
    cuzdan_rc=rootView.findViewById(R.id.cuzdan_recycler_view);
    api = ApiClient.getClient().create(CoinMarketApi.class);
    CoinList();
    RecyclerBagla(rootView);


    return rootView;
}
private void RecyclerBagla(View rootView) {
    cuzdan_rc=rootView.findViewById(R.id.cuzdan_recycler_view);
    cuzdanList = new ArrayList<>();
    cuzdanModels = new CuzdanDao().Cuzdan(vt);
    adapter = new CuzdanAdapter(getActivity(),cuzdanModels,cuzdanList);

    cuzdan_rc.setAdapter(adapter);
    cuzdan_rc.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


}
public void CoinList() {
    Call<CryptoModel> call = api.coinMarketListCall("500");


    call.enqueue(new Callback<CryptoModel>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CryptoModel> call, Response<CryptoModel> response) {

            CryptoModel list = response.body();

            cuzdanList.clear();
            cuzdanList.addAll(list.getData());
         

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CryptoModel> call, Throwable t) {
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onFailure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("XXXX", t.getLocalizedMessage());
            call.cancel();
        }
    });

}
```

And this is Adaptar class;

```
public class CuzdanAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CuzdanAdapter.CardTasarimTutucu> {

private Context context;
private List<CuzdanModel> cuzdanList;
private List<Datum> mData;
public CuzdanAdapter(Context context, List<CuzdanModel> cuzdanList,List<Datum> mData) {
    this.context = context;
    this.cuzdanList = cuzdanList;
    this.mData=mData;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public CardTasarimTutucu onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cuzdan_rc_tasarim, parent, false);
    return new CardTasarimTutucu(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CardTasarimTutucu holder, int position) {

    Datum datum = mData.get(position);

    CuzdanModel cuzdan = cuzdanList.get(position);
    holder.textViewCoinDegeriAdapter.setText(String.valueOf(datum.getQuote().getUSD().getPrice()));
    holder.textViewCoinAdi.setText(cuzdan.getCoin_adi());

    holder.textViewAlisFiyatiAdapter.setText(String.format("%.3f",cuzdan.getCoin_alis_fiyati()));
    holder.textViewCoinAdediAdapter.setText(String.format("%.3f",cuzdan.getCoin_alis_adeti()));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cuzdanList.size();
}

public class CardTasarimTutucu extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView textViewCoinAdi, textViewCoinDegisimAdapter,
            textViewCoinAdediAdapter, textViewCoinDegeriAdapter, textViewAlisFiyatiAdapter;
    private CardView cuzdan_cardView;

    public CardTasarimTutucu(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewCoinAdi = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCoinAdiAdapter);
        textViewCoinDegisimAdapter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCoinDegisimAdapter);
        textViewCoinAdediAdapter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCoinAdediAdapter);
        textViewCoinDegeriAdapter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCoinDegeriAdapter);
        textViewAlisFiyatiAdapter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAlisFiyatiAdapter);
        cuzdan_cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cuzdan_cardView);


    }
}


}
```

Why it is not working? I need your help.

Comment: Have no idea what you are trying to do. I don't see 2 lists. Please tell us where you get this array out of bounds exception.

Comment: please verify cuzdanModels contains data... before adapter set up.

Comment: @DavidWasser arrays are defined in adapter. The errors are as followsCuzdanAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CuzdanAdapter.java:38)
CuzdanAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CuzdanAdapter.java:17)   java 38 points to this line ''Datum datum = mData.get(position);'' and java 17 points to this "public class CuzdanAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CuzdanAdapter.CardTasarimTutucu>"

Comment: @hafiza I already using cuzdanModels in another fragment and it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create and initialize the adapter like this:

```
cuzdanList = new ArrayList<>();
cuzdanModels = new CuzdanDao().Cuzdan(vt);
adapter = new CuzdanAdapter(getActivity(),cuzdanModels,cuzdanList);
```

At this point `cuzdanList` is empty. Obviously you need to have exactly the same number of items in `cuzdanList` as you have in `cuzdanModels` and that isn't happening. At the time of the crash, `List<cuzdanModels>` has more than 0 elements and `List<Datum>` is still empty.

The fact that you refer to the `List<CuzdanModel>` as `cuzdanList` and the `List<Datum>` as `mData` in the adapter, but call the adapter constructor using `cuzdanList` as the `List<Datum>` might be part of your problem.

Comment: Sorry sir i didn't understand what you mean exactly. What can you suggest me?  I can not do anything my hands are tied.

Comment: I have no idea what "my hands are tied" is supposed to mean. This is your code, you can do whatever you want. Anyway, you need to make sure that the 2 lists you pass to your adapter have the same number of elements. They don't One list has more than zero elements and the other list is empty. Fix it by filling both lists. Either that or fix the `getItemCount()` method so that it only returns the minimum number of items in both lists: `return Math.min(cuzdanList.size(), mData.size())`

Comment: Please don't be mad at me. I know it's my code but i couldn't do whatever I want. Because my knowledge is unfortunately  insufficient. For example, it would never have occurred to me to use the method you used. Because I didn't even know there was such a method. Anyway thank you so much sir. Your suggest is solved this problem. I'm grateful.

Comment: I'm happy you were able to solve the problem. If my answer was helpful, you should "accept" it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer. Welcome to the Stackoverflow community.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` indicates that you are trying to get an element from a list (or an array or some other collection), but the list does not have it. More specifically, `Size: 0` says that your list has 0 elements, so it is empty, and `Index: 0` says that you are trying to get first element. But the list is empty, so there is no first element, therefore you get the exception.

You added that the exception happens on line 38 that is `'Datum datum = mData.get(position);`. Seems like at that point `position` is 0, and `mData` is empty. Looking at your code, I did not find any line in `Adapter` class where you put something into `mData`, you only initialize it in `CuzdanAdapter` constructor. And that is called at line `adapter = new CuzdanAdapter(getActivity(),cuzdanModels,cuzdanList);`, where `cuzdanList` is created empty two lines before. The only place in the Fragment file where you put anything in `cuzdanList` is line `cuzdanList.addAll(list.getData());`. But if the response is empty, no elements will be added, and later you get the IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: I understand what you mean sir.  But it's still not working.I deleted "cuzdanList = new ArrayList<>();" command but nothing's happened. I think the problem is bigger than my knowledge.I couldn't fix it. Anyway thank you for your answer